# Filepond style is not rendering

Tags: node.js, filepond

I m building an e-library.i m using a couple of FilePond plugins ... I copied all the css
And js scripts and pasted it ...then i registered the plugins but when i m using filepond class it has no effect

```
 <link href="https://unpkg.com/filepond/dist/filepond.css" rel="stylesheet">
 <link href="https://unpkg.com/filepond-plugin-image-preview/dist/filepond- 
  plugin-image-preview.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

 <script defer src="https://unpkg.com/filepond-plugin-image- 
  preview/dist/filepond-plugin-image-preview.js"></script>

 <script defer src="https://unpkg.com/filepond-plugin-file- 
  encode/dist/filepond-plugin-file-encode.js"></script>

 <script defer src="https://unpkg.com/filepond-plugin-image- 
  resize/dist/filepond-plugin-image-resize.js"></script>

 <script defer src="https://unpkg.com/filepond/dist/filepond.js"></script>
```

then i registered the plugins in a js file:

```
FilePond.registerPlugin(
    FilePondPluginImagePreview,
    FilePondPluginImageResize,
    FilePondPluginFileEncode,
)

FilePond.setOptions({
    stylePanelAspectRatio:150/100,
    imageResizeTargetWidth:100,
    imageResizeTargetHeight:150
})
FilePond.parse(document.body)
```

and i m using it on a file input:

```
<div>
    <label>Cover</label>
    <input type="file" name="cover" class="filepond">
</div>
```

Still it has no effect ....i don't understand what's wrong..

Comment: Please edit your question and post your code in code blocks. Don't post images of it.

Comment: Do you have any error on your browser console?

Comment: No........i double checked all the links ....it's strange